# Extracting first element of an array fails with underscore.js

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

i'm currently working on  a back-end website in Angular with very  little underscore.js.
For my back-end i'm using the php-framework Laravel 4 which is very Handy.
The problem i'm facing is :

When i query an url with angular the response is nice and clean so i can ng-repeat with no problem. But when i'm trying to extract the first element of the response with underscore, it gives me : undefined.

here's an extract of the code of my Controller:

```
var Client = $resource('myUrl/that/works/fine/and/returns/well');

var resultat = Client.query();

$scope.clients = resultat ;

$scope.isAnArray = _.isArray(resultat); // it returns true;
```

if i now try the line bellow $scope.myFirstElemInArray is undefined ???

```
$scope.myFirstElemInArray = _.first(resultat ); // expected:the first element.
```

I really don't see what's wrong with it. Here's the content of my variable resultat:

```
 [{"id":"2","email":"olivier@example.com"},{"id":"3","email":"mezigh@example.com"}]
```

If somebody can give a little help, i'm really getting crazy with this
Olivier (Fr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use callback for this i believe. Here is what the `$resource` documentation says

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most case one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods.

something like

```
Client.query(function(data) {
$scope.myFirstElemInArray = _.first(data);
});
```